# Display long country names as short country names from a Country table in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2

A question about representing a string from a model.

I have a `Country` model which has a list of countries.

The countries are in long form eg. United States, United Kingdom, etc.

I want to represent this data in short name form eg. USA, UK.

I don't really want to change the names on the table column because on my forms I would like keep the long form names.

I thought I would add code in the model `Country.rb` if self.id == 123 "USA" but I'm sure this isn't the right way.

Any help will be grand.

Much appreciated.

WD

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is better to store short names in additional field, see below links:

- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Country_code
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-3

Answer (score 1):

You can add shortform column or you can select first letter of longform name,
or if you can use rails helper for country select http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#time-zone-and-country-select